# how to handle user session into the oauth provider?

Tags: java, session, oauth, jersey, provider

I finalize my OAuth 1.0a provider based on Jersey but I'm facing a small issue I don't know how to deal with

During the OAuth dance, the user has to authenticate with his credentials (login/password)

With my implementation, for the moment, he has to authenticate every time

During the authorization step, the only token which is sent to the web service is the request token related to the consumer

Jersey doesn't manage session

How can I avoid to ask authentication if the user is already authenticate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The client application which uses your oAuth provider should maintain state in the session. As a minimum it has to keep the access token as that will be needed to access the user's data. The presence of a valid access token could be used as an indicator that the user is authenticated.

Comment: I agree that clients have to maintain sessions. but if a user already authenticated by the web service wants to use another client, this client doesn't have any information about previous access token. so there is no valid indicator for the web service about a session

Comment: @futoshita - if you want different clients to reuse the same authentication then this is Single Sign On (SSO), which is not related to oAuth.

Comment: when I first connect to twitter, I need to sign in with login/password. if I want to connect to about.me with my twitter account I'm redirected to the twitter site and I just need to authorize about.me. this is what I want. is it sso?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that when the user first authenticates to the web service, the web service should provide a login cookie  which is validated each time the user wants to authorize a new client

could you assess this method?

now I need to find how handle cookie with jersey...